# How to get SVM in MALLET

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, mallet

I have been using MALLET for sometime now and I want to train the data using the SVM classifier. Is there a way I can get SVM on MALLET. I followed the instructions at [SVM on MALLET](http://nlpthings.blogspot.in/2014/03/support-vector-machine-within-mallet.html) but it didn't help much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to implement the SVM in WEKA or in Python with Scikit-Learn. Why use Mallet for SVM?